# Function is designed to execute every 15 clicks, but always executes on the first click

Tags: swift

I have a counter designed to display an advertisement every time the user clicks "play again." On the 15th play, they get an ad. The problem is that it always displays an ad(function runs) after the first click, and then it obeys the 15 click logic. I want to fix this because the ad is coming too early in the game. Here is my code:

```
@objc func playAgain(_ sender: Any) {
    if counter % 15 == 0 {
        if Appodeal.isReadyForShow(with: .interstitial) {
            Appodeal.showAd(AppodealShowStyle.interstitial, rootViewController: self)
        } else {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HouseAd")
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    }
    counter += 1
}
```

I expect it to display after every 15 clicks but it always runs after the first click and then obeys the logic.

Comment: because 0%15 is == 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase value of `counter` before `if` statement, so after first click value which comes to condition will be 1 and not 0 (`0%15==0` returns `true`). Also you can change value to 0 every time that counter is 15 and then you can just compare two numbers:

```
counter += 1
if counter == 15 { 
    counter = 0
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it now. Such a simple thing to overlook.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your logic shows the ad after the **16th** click because the counter starts at 0.

You could do

```
if counter == 14 {
   counter = 0
   // show ad
} else { counter += 1 }
```

or

```
guard counter < 14 else {
   counter = 0
   // show ad
   return
} 
counter += 1
```

This avoids also an `Int` overflow in a couple of hundred years

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This could be another way to fulfill the requirement. I went with Robert's answer so I just moved one line before the if statement so it doesn't return true on first tap.